# How to serialize an array of polymorphic objects to file using Protocol Buffers?

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

Having an array `std::vector<BaseClass*>` what is the correct way of saving this array to a file using Google's Protocol Buffers library?

`BaseClass` is a base class of hierarchy of classes, it has several sub classes. 
Is Google's Protocol Buffers even suitable for this purpose or maybe another library would be preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it said above, you have to use extension mechanism to implement polymorphism. 
This link you may find useful http://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism/

Answer (score 2):

You could create a list-message `MyList` which contains elements of type `Class`. And there you need a specific message for each subclass:

```
message MyList{
    repeated Class entry = 1;
}

message Class{
    required BaseProperties baseProperties = 1;

    oneof{
        SubClassOne sub_one_properties = 2;
        SubClassTwo sub_two_properties = 3;
        ...
    }
}

message BaseProperties{
    //contains common properties of BaseClass
}

message SubClassOne{
    //contains specific properties of one this SubClass
}

message SubClassTwo{
    //contains specific properties of one this SubClass
}
```

If you don't like the `oneof` keyword, or are using an older libprotobuf, you can also insert an enum with typeinformations and add corresponding optional messagefields:

```
message Class{
    enum ClassType{
        SUB_CLASS_ONE = 1;
        SUB_CLASS_TWO = 2;
    }

    required ClassType type = 1;
    required BaseProperties baseProperties = 2;

    optional SubClassOne sub_one_properties = 3;
    optional SubClassTwo sub_two_properties = 4;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Protocol Buffers allow for repeated fields these act like `std::vector` in your code. As for polymorphic objects, you can use the extension framework. See [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) under the extension header.